# Use dynamic data in Chart.js with Node.Js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, chart.js

Router:

```
router.get('/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    Answer.findOne({ post: req.params.id }, function (error, answer) {
        Post.findOne({ _id: answer.post }, function (err, post) {
            res.render('post/stats', { title: post.ask });
        });
    });
});
```

Chart function:

```
var chart = new Chart($("#answerChart"), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "",
      backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: '{{ title }}'
    }
  }
});

chart.data.labels[0] = "Yes";
chart.data.labels[1] = "Test";
chart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = 5;
chart.data.datasets[0].data[1] = 3;
```

And I need to retrieve data dynamically from mongoose but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Basically two things. 1. You should implement an additional API endpoint which responds desired data, 2. You should implement AJAX call to fetch that data and plug it into chart.js library.

Answer (score 1):

you can stringify in nodejs code as below

```
router.get('/doughnut', function(req, res) {
  data = [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40, 62, 85, 76, 65, 81];
  console.log('doughnut data',data);
  res.render('dashboard/doughnut', {
    title:'My First Doughnut Chart', 
    datai: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
});

and in .pug template you parse it like
var idata = JSON.parse('!{datai}');
```

https://github.com/hiralyshah/chartjs_mongoose_mongoDB